# How can I read uitextview text line by line iOS?

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, ios5, uitextview

I have uitextview with text. I want to read it line by line. I want to it for up to iOS 5 and without `- (BOOL)textView:(UITextView *)textView shouldChangeTextInRange:(NSRange)range replacementText:(NSString *)text;` delegate method. How can I do that?

Comment: If the lines are separated by "\n" then you can follow @Mr_bem's code, and if not and you are working on iOS7 then you can try -santhu suggestion. If its not the case, then you can't get read the text in each line with 100 percent accuracy, trust me I have tried all the methods. If you could tell what you want to achieve, I can suggest something.

Answer (score 12):

You can use the textview's layout manager to get those. But it is available from iOS 7. You can use layout manager's method - ( **enumerateLineFragmentsForGlyphRange:usingBlock:** )

The below code prints the result as shown

```
textView.text =@"abcdsakabsbdkjflk sadjlkasjdlk asjkdasdklj asdpaandjs bajkhdb hasdskjbnas kdbnkja sbnkasj dbkjasd kjk aj";

NSLog(@"%d",_textView.text.length); // length here is 104.

[_textView.layoutManager enumerateLineFragmentsForGlyphRange:NSMakeRange(0, 104) usingBlock:^(CGRect rect, CGRect usedRect, NSTextContainer *textContainer, NSRange glyphRange, BOOL *stop) {

NSLog(@"rect %@ - usedRect %@ - glymph Rangle %d %d -",NSStringFromCGRect(rect),NSStringFromCGRect(usedRect),glyphRange.location,glyphRange.length);
    }]
;
```

print result

```
2013-12-17 12:48:40.250 testEmpty[675:a0b] rect {{0, 0}, {200, 13.8}} - usedRect {{0, 0}, {176.08398, 13.8}} - glymph Rangle 0 31 -
2013-12-17 12:48:40.251 testEmpty[675:a0b] rect {{0, 13.8}, {200, 13.8}} - usedRect {{0, 13.8}, {182.11328, 13.8}} - glymph Rangle 31 31 -
2013-12-17 12:48:40.251 testEmpty[675:a0b] rect {{0, 27.6}, {200, 13.8}} - usedRect {{0, 27.6}, {168.75977, 13.8}} - glymph Rangle 62 28 -
2013-12-17 12:48:40.252 testEmpty[675:a0b] rect {{0, 41.400002}, {200, 13.8}} - usedRect {{0, 41.400002}, {82.035156, 13.8}} - glymph Rangle 90 14 -
```

So in each run of the block, you will get the **glymphRange.length** as length of the string used in that line.

Answer (score 6):

Use:

```
NSArray *lines = [textView.text componentsSeparatedByString:@"\n"];
```

Your array has the lines, each line is in an index.

Comment: If we use return key for new line we can use this. But I want to read line by line without entering return key.

Answer (score 4):

Expanding on @santhu's answer, here is a Swift 4 answer:

```
textView.text = "this is some long text, that is one continuous string but is on different lines."

textView.layoutManager.enumerateLineFragments(forGlyphRange: NSRange(location: 0, length: text.count)) { (rect, usedRect, textContainer, glyphRange, stop) in

    let characterRange = textView.layoutManager.characterRange(forGlyphRange: glyphRange, actualGlyphRange: nil)
    let line = (textView.text as NSString).substring(with: characterRange)
    print(line)
    print("----------------------------------------------")
}

print("----------------------------------------------")
print("----------------------------------------------")
```

Output:

```
this is some long text, t
----------------------------------------------
hat is one continuous str
----------------------------------------------
ing but is on different lin
----------------------------------------------
es.
----------------------------------------------
----------------------------------------------
----------------------------------------------
```